# Semantic UI inverted dimmer not working with multiple modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, semantic-ui

I have seen several similar questions asked but didn't find a solution. Basically the inverted/blurred dimmer didn't work for me either when specified for individual modals, or the entire .ui.basic.united.modal class.

I had multiple united modals opening in sequence with only one open at a time.

I would really appreciate any updates on this issue! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```
<div class="ui dimmable dimmed segment">
<div class="ui simple inverted dimmer"></div>
  <p>Learning from the past</p>
  <p>CSS Layout today</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Your example works, but when I switch the content from the simple paragraph to a modal, the dimmer is no longer inverted. Any ideas?

Comment: Adding <div class="ui simple inverted dimmer"></div> was what helped me.  I'm still missing the dimmable and dimmed classes on the body but I'm half way there now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when you have multiple modals the JavaScript got crazy and removed or did not add the class inverted to the dimmer component. So a quick fix would be putting the class after you create the modals, like this:

```
$('.ui.dimmer.modals').addClass('inverted');
```

This worked for me.